# VB.NET Automatic Process Kill?

Tags: vb.net, process, while-loop

Recently, this small, annoying, and random process from Yahoo, which I don't even use, has been starting randomly, and will begin taking up around 2000k memory. I have coded something I thought will automatically stop the process when it begins running, although it does not preform correct, nor does it do what I want it to do. This is what I have compiled:

```
Dim arrProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("YahooUIService")
Dim constant As Integer

While constant = 5 'This is in the form
For Each p As Process In arrProcess
            p.Kill()
        Next
End While
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how I can correct myself? I know VB.NET well, although yes, there are many small things like this that throw me off.

Comment: Don’t write a program to do it. Find out *why* it’s starting. Run `msconfig` (or Task Manager on Windows 8) and check your startup applications. Check your services. Google the process name.

Comment: I'll do this. Thanks for the fast response. I'll keep you informed on the results.

Comment: @minitech This is most likely some sort of virus. The executable resides in /system, and I'm highly doubtful that Yahoo would put something in there. I'm currently unsure whether to delete it or not. There is also a similar executable, although apparently it's an official one, named YahooAUService.exe.

Comment: This would only detect the app if it was open at the time your app started.  To continuously detect the app you'd have to call GetProcessesByName() INSIDE your While loop.  Definitely put some kind of delay in there, though, as otherwise you'll ramp up CPU usage to 100%.  It'd be better to use a Timer() control and check for the process in the Tick() event.

Comment: @Batchista: Get an antivirus?

Comment: @Idle_Mind should put his/her comment as the answer so it can be marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would only detect the app if it was open at the time your app started. To continuously detect the app you'd have to call GetProcessesByName() INSIDE your While loop. Definitely put some kind of delay in there, though, as otherwise you'll ramp up CPU usage to 100%. It'd be better to use a Timer() control and check for the process in the Tick() event.

Comment: Thanks, this was in fact very useful. Seeing as I do not want to delete this file, knowing what that could lead up to. Timer() seems like a great option, although I may attempt to try Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) inside of the while, to see how much CPU it takes up. I want this to be a very small CPU usage.